# autofs not working after update to Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mount, cifs, autofs

I use autofs to mount the drives of our server (cifs), which worked fine in the past. After updating Ubuntu from 15.04 (Vivid) to 15.10 (Wily), these mountpoints regularly hangup. *ls /mnt/serverdrive/{mountpoint}* will not give any results, but causes the terminal to freeze. I had similar issues when using fstab in the past- and thought this to be a timeout of our windows-server. Autofs was the solution at that time.

However, I do not know what causes this freeze in autofs and do not know where to search for the problem. After some time the mountpoints are occasionally accessible again. No problem with access via Nautilus, though.

When upgrading to 15.10, I copied my configs into the new (default) auto.master. My config of *auto.master* is given below. The configs in *auto.cifs-shares* are my previous ones and unchanged.

*sudo service restart autofs* does not help, either.

Is it a problem in my configs or a problem of new autofs-packages? Eventually also related to: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/autofs/+bug/1503034 ?

Thanks everyone!

```
    #
    # Sample auto.master file
    # This is a 'master' automounter map and it has the following format:
    # mount-point [map-type[,format]:]map [options]
    # For details of the format look at auto.master(5).
    #
    #/misc  /etc/auto.misc
    #
    # NOTE: mounts done from a hosts map will be mounted with the
    #   "nosuid" and "nodev" options unless the "suid" and "dev"
    #   options are explicitly given.
    #
    #/net   -hosts
    #
    # Include /etc/auto.master.d/*.autofs
    # The included files must conform to the format of this file.
    #
    +dir:/etc/auto.master.d
    #
    # Include central master map if it can be found using
    # nsswitch sources.
    #
    # Note that if there are entries for /net or /misc (as
    # above) in the included master map any keys that are the
    # same will not be seen as the first read key seen takes
    # precedence.
    #
    +auto.master

    # Own configs from ubuntu 15.04                    
    /mnt/merkur /etc/auto.cifs-shares
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get some clues, follow debug steps:

7. Debugging Auto Mount Problems

If you are having trouble automounting your file systems, it may be useful to run automount in the foreground.

1. Stop the autofs daemon

   ```
   sudo service autofs stop
   ```
2. Run automount in the foreground with verbose information

   ```
   sudo automount -f -v
   ```
3. From another terminal, try to mount your file-systems by changing directories into the mountpoint.
4. Check the output from the first terminal for clues as to why the mount failed or was not attempted.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs

Comment: The answer is helpful, but did not solve my problem.  I haven't lost mountpoints recently, so my issue seems to have been solved - probably through updated packages from Ubuntu. Thanks for your help anyway.